# Removing Santa hat from QGIS icon?

Tags: installation, icon, qgis-2.18

I just upgraded to QGIS 2.18.1 Las Palmas.

This comes with a Santa hat on the icon in the top right corner and windows bar.

[image]

Is it possible to remove this from my installation?

Comment: You can pretend that it is not christmas time and set your computer's clock to something else.

Comment: I'd like to know how to remove this also. I'm putting together some tutorials with QGIS which involve screenshots, which will look odd come July.

Comment: Turns out this is easily changed without a recompile. It's possible to replace a couple of the icon files. On Linux they are located at `/usr/share/qgis/images/icons`.

Comment: Go to `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\images\icons` or `C:\Program Files\QGIS X version\apps\qgis\images\icons` and replace xmas icons (16x16 and 60x60) with original icons or another icon. In OS X, they are located in `/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/images/icons`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your only real option is to replace the files in:

Windows: `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\images\icons` or `C:\Program Files\QGIS X version\apps\qgis\images\icons`

Linux: `/usr/share/qgis/images/icons`

OSX: `/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/images/icons`

It's hard coded to change the icon for the 12th month of the year.

I added the feature, and no I didn't consider if someone would get offended by a Santa hat, because:

- Santa is considered generally secular where I am from (QGIS is a multicultural code base)
- I did it in my free time for a bit of fun (aka it's an easter egg)
- No one paid me to do it better or smarter

As it's a simple file replace you are more than welcome to make a plugin to replace the files for people who don't like the icon.  I'm also a plugin moderator so if you write it I can fast track the approval for you :)

Thanks to @Snorfalorpagus and @aldo_tapia for the path locations on each platform.

Comment: My first thought when I saw it was that a file had been downloaded/installed by QGIS, which is not exactly a good way to build the trust of users. Seeing your answer leads to another concern: unnecessary features / bloat, which is not ideal, however small / funny.

Comment: If you consider a small easter egg bloat I'm not sure we are on the same path here.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2005/10/21/why-no-easter-eggs/

Comment: @NathanW Hi Nathan, as I should have responded earlier - I really appreciate the work people like you put into invaluable open resources like QGIS, you make the world a better place. I just don't like cultural imperialism in general, however inadvertent, and am a grinch more specifically. Thanks though for your helpful answer